# How to run CountDownTimer from positive to negative values?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to display a total delay time of the vehicle, So I have to run a timer from positive to the negative direction. Here Positive time is the deadline which will be inserted at the beginning & as the timer goes in negative mode, It will represent the delay of a vehicle. Just suppose Timer starts from 12:00:00 and it will reach to 05:00:00 after 7 hours and -03:00:00 after 8 hours and so on. It's a continuous timer decreasing second by second. So can I do this with [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) or anything else?

I have already tried [jgilfelt/android-countdown](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-countdown) but it does not calculate negative time.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this functionality is use [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) with  [jgilfelt/android-countdown](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-countdown) library.

First start [CountdownChronometer](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-countdown/blob/master/src/com/readystatesoftware/countdown/CountdownChronometer.java)  and as it finished then start simple [chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) with prefix "-"

You have to hide CountDownChronometer on this event. To catch the completion event use below code...

```
    countdownChronometer.setOnCompleteListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            countdownChronometer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.chronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.chronometer.setFormat("- %s");
            this.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            this.chronometer.start();
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You know it is not a better solution, but I've no other way so at this time I'm going to use this method. Well thanks.